# Jython - import module does not work when run from Eclipse

Tags: import, module, websphere, jython

I have a script 'localfunc.py' with different functions, and a main script 'doIt.py' with the following import code:

```
import localfunc

localfunc.aMethodToExecute()
```

I'm new to Python/Jython, but i think this is correct, right?

My problem is that when executed in Eclipse onto my local websphere server (right clic on script->Run as -> execute as administrative script) i get the following error message:

> ImportError: no module named localfunc.

I'm using WAS 8.5.2 and Jython version is 2.1 for information.

Somebody has an idea why it's not working with Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easy finally to solve this problem. In your running configuration, update the setting in 'Arguments' > working directory by selecting 'other' and your main script directory.

For example if your working directory looks like:

```
src/scripts/
        start.py
        lib/
            localfunc.py
```

Select 'src/scripts/'

It works now.